# Como calcular a Quantidade dos números pares desse vetor?

Tags: php

Criar um vetor com 7 elementos inteiros. Imprimir o maior e o menor,
sem ordenar, o percentual de números pares. Só falta esse percentual.

```
         echo "Maior valor: ".max($num);
         echo "</br> Menor valor: ".min($num)."</br>";

         foreach ($num as $numero){
                echo "$numero ";

         }


    ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifique se o resto da divisão de cada número por 2 é igual a 0. Se for, adicione a um contador.

```
<?php
// Porcentagem de pares
$array = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
$contador = 0; // Responsavel por contar o numero de pares
foreach($array as $numero) {
    if($numero % 2 == 0) {
        $contador++;
    }
}
$porcentagemPares = ($contador/6)*100; //Divide o numero de pares pelo numero total de elementos e multiplica por 100
echo "Porcentagem de pares " .$porcentagemPares. "%";
```

Exemplo funcionando: https://ideone.com/p9kBix

Comment: Valeu! :) Obrigada!